# k8s get resources from cluster take too much time

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I need to get all resources based on **label**, I used the following code **which works**, However, it takes **too much time** ( ~20sec) to get the response, even which I restrict it to only one namespace (vrf), any idea what im doing wrong here?

```
resource.NewBuilder(flags).
   Unstructured().
   ResourceTypes(res...).
   NamespaceParam("vrf").AllNamespaces(false).
   LabelSelectorParam("a=b").SelectAllParam(selector == "").
   Flatten().
   Latest().Do().Object()
```

https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/cli-runtime@v0.26.1/pkg/resource#Builder

As I already using `label` and `ns`, not sure what should else I do in this case.

Ive checked the cluster connection and it seems that everything is ok, running regular `kubectl` are getting **very fast** response, just this query took much time.

Comment: maybe your connection to the cluster is really bad? I've had 3-5 second calls to a cluster in Japan once. 20 seems a bit too much though

Comment: No the connection is just fine as others request to the cluster is working blazing fast...

Answer (score 1):

The search may be heavy due to the sheer size of the resources the query has to search into. Have you looked into this possibility and further reduce the size using one more label or filter on top of current.

Also check the performance of you Kubernetes api server when the operation is being performed and optimize it.

Comment: Thanks, how can I reduce the size ? I already use `ns` and `label`? can you please provide a code example of what you mean?